# linq SelectMany and Regex.Split clr

Tags: .net, regex, linq, c#-4.0, clr4.0

I have a list of strings, that each string needs to split by a regex, than kept in the same list.

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.Add("big string with a lot of words");
a=a.SelectMany(item=> Regex.Split("\r\n",item)).ToList();
```

I just want to make sure that this will not reorder the parts of the string that were created?

Is there a web site that has information about methods runtime and compiler optimizations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Linq-to-Objects, it will not re-order the elements of the result set unless you call `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`.

However, I wouldn't use regular expressions for this, a simple [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would do just fine:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.Add("big string with a lot of words");
a = a.SelectMany(item => item.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToList();
```

Comment: I just simplified the code here, I am actually using a different regex.... You think that if after this code I will print the strings in the list I will always get the string I started with?